# Laravel error: Target [Illuminate\View\Engines\EngineInterface] is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating an abstract class that will grab the contents of a view using Laravel's View class. But I'm getting the following error when trying to run a method from a class that extends it:

```
Illuminate \ Container \ BindingResolutionException
Target [Illuminate\View\Engines\EngineInterface] is not instantiable.
```

Here's my code:

**PdfReport.php**

```
use Illuminate\View\View as View;

abstract class PdfReport {

  private $view;

  function __construct(View $view)
  {
      $this->view = $view;
  }

  public function render($reportView, $report)
  {
      $this->view->make('report.pdf.' . $reportView, ['report' => $report])->render();
  }

}
```

**EslReport.php**

```
<?php namespace Reports\PdfReports;

class EslPdfReport extends PdfReport {

    public function renderReport($report)
    {
        return $this->render('esl', $report);
    }

}
```

Then I'm running my code in **routes.php** for testing purposes as follows:

```
use Reports\PdfReports\EslPdfReport;

Route::get('pdftest', array(    
    'as' => 'pdftest',
        function(){
            $eslReport = App::make('Reports\PdfReports\EslPdfReport');
            $eslReport->renderReport(EslReport::find(1));
        }
));
```

I'm not quite understanding if I'm doing something wrong with the dependency injection for the view in the abstract class, it's all pretty new concepts to me, so any help would be most appreciated.

Also I asked this question on laracasts forum if it helps: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/confusion-about-constructors-in-abstract-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Illuminate\View\View` you need to inject `Illuminate\View\Factory`:

```
use Illuminate\View\Factory as View;
```

[Here's a reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades#facade-class-reference) of facade classes and there actual underlying class you need to use when working with DI

Comment: Thanks for your reply @lukasgeiter - however now I'm getting this error when using your suggestion above: `ReflectionException Class Illuminate\View\Factory does not exist`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Thought it was 4.2, it's 4.1, I'm guessing I need to upgrade?

Comment: Upgrade would be best. Or use `Illuminate\View\Environment`

Comment: Thanks that seemed to get rid of the error so I've marked the question as answered, but it doesn't appear to be returning the view any ideas?

Comment: There's no need to call `render()`. Maybe removing that will make it work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I tried removing it and it didn't work sadly. I was using `render()` to return the view as a string which I'd place in DOMPDF's `loadHTML()` method to output it as a PDF. Get the feeling I'm approaching this all wrong!

Comment: I see. Well actually then `render()` should work. Maybe upgrading to 4.2 fixes it I don't know... What do you get returned currently?

Comment: When I run `dd($eslReport->renderReport(EslReport::find(6)));` in my routes file I get `NULL`, perhaps its best I do a bit of tinkering and set up a separate question?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, since it's likely that it's something entirely unrelated to the original error...